# ASP:ListBox - no selected items on postback?

Tags: asp.net, listbox, selecteditem

I have the following markup:

```
<tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Available Roles" />
        <br />
        <asp:ListBox ID="availableRolesListBox" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="100px" Rows="10" AutoPostBack="false" />
    </td>
    <td valign="top" align="center">
        &nbsp;
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="addToRole" runat="server" Text="--->" OnClick="addToRole_Click" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="removeFromRole" runat="server" Text="<---" OnClick="removeFromRole_Click" />
    </td>
    <td valign="top" align="left">
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="User In Roles" />
        <br />
        <asp:ListBox ID="userInRolesListBox" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="100px" Rows="10" AutoPostBack="false" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

And the following in code-behind:

```
protected void addToRole_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add user to the selected role...
    foreach (ListItem myItem in availableRolesListBox.Items)
    {
        if (myItem.Selected)
        {
            Roles.AddUserToRole(userListBox.SelectedItem.Value, myItem.Text);
        }
    }

    Refresh();
}
```

When I step into the code-behind absolutely no items are selected!  What am I forgetting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you perhaps rebinding the `availableRolesListBox` each time, instead of if(!IsPostback)?

Comment: Ah crap! You got it on the head.  My Refresh() method (repopulates most controls) was outside of my !Page.PostBack.  <arggghhhh/>

Thanks!

Comment: Don't feel bad- it's an easy mistake to make!

Comment: Usually I have dynamic controls I must create on each request(so they are there to receive postback values).  In this case I still needed to create the listbox, but I needed to leave it empty(moving the code that populates it to !IsPostBack section).  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could check a few things.

CHeck that you are NOT reloading the listbox after each postback.  Also, you might want to make sure you do not have `ViewStateEnabled="false"` for a parent container.

Other than that your code looks like it should be ok, debugging any further would require more code or information.